# How do I know on which IDE to edit a project's source code?

Tags: compiling, source, debugging, ide

**EDIT**:

Thanks to all answerers and commenters, there's enough material to keep me busy for a while !

---

I recently switch to Linux and wanted to do my first development steps with the following source:

[SDL Sopwith](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sdl-sopwith/files/)

Beside compiling and running the program with the following lines :

```
./configure
make
```

I couldn't figure out how to easily edit a project's source code but by editing it manually in a text editor and typing the above lines every time to test it ... without debugging and all the features that are provided by an IDE.

There are other projects (i.e. [AntiMicro](http://www.ryochan7.com/projects/antimicro/)) that I figured out how to edit in a particular IDE such as QT Creator because there was a .PRO file in the project which I quickly found out what it was for.

How do someone gets a source running in an IDE when there are no IDE-specific file included in it ?

Comment: if there aren't files tied to a specific IDE and that's the entire build process, just choose an IDE. possibly one that's suited to the language the project is written in. (you don't have to use an IDE, though. I don't; I just use a text editor.)

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but how do you find your marks in the project without some features provided by an IDE ? Are you a Real Programmer ? :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Programmer

Comment: Maybe more experienced. Right tool for the job. Also may people don't check in their editors/IDEs project files as they are specific to the machine/user and not to the code.  Personally I despise all IDEs and favor A good text editor, but that Is just me, to each his own.

Comment: No dependencies is certainly a good thing, it'll take some time for me to get on par with it : I've been baby-sitted for years by Visual Studio and Resharper ...

Comment: @Aybe I'm not sure what you mean by "marks", but I've never gotten lost in a project. I never work on projects as big as, say, the Linux Kernel or Gecko. I work on very small projects and just never get lost. It also depends on what you consider an IDE, e.g. I consider Emacs an editor, not an IDE, but some would argue otherwise. (Side note: I _love_ The Story of Mel!)

Comment: Marks? Good text editors can be integrated with ctags and cscope to navigate source code.

Comment: @strugee bad translation from me ! I meant : http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/trouver+ses+marques.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `vim` or `gvim`, [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), or [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). Eclipse works surprisingly well for other languages, it's primarily suited to Java but through the use of plugins can be adapted to suite other languages too.

- [Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Tooling)](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

*excerpt*

> The CDT Project provides a fully functional C and C++ Integrated Development Environment based on the Eclipse platform. Features include: support for project creation and managed build for various toolchains, standard make build, source navigation, various source knowledge tools, such as type hierarchy, call graph, include browser, macro definition browser, code editor with syntax highlighting, folding and hyperlink navigation, source code refactoring and code generation, visual debugging tools, including memory, registers, and disassembly viewers.

#### Other options

**QT Creator** - Again if it's C++ development then you could try [QT Creator](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator). I have no practical experience with this one but it shouldn't be any harder than Eclipse and there is excellent documentation.

**Code Blocks** - Code Blocks is another one. Spelled [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/). This one I have some experience with and it's OK, but doesn't seem as popular as others. We use it for an internal project that we support. It does the job.

**KDevelop** - [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) is another one, never used it.

If none of those suite your needs then I'd start going through this ancient question from SO, titled: [C++ IDE for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux).

Also check out this Q&A from programmers SE site, titled: [Comparison of IDEs for C++ and C development on Linux: KDevelop, Eclipse, NetBeans, CodeBlocks and Anjuta [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125796/comparison-of-ides-for-c-and-c-development-on-linux-kdevelop-eclipse-netbea).

Comment: That looks like the right answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `.pro` file and then open in Qt creator i find it easy. All you have to do is to find .c and .h files and put the path in the .pro file. Search for `qmake`, another idea is to make a script which will parse the `Makefile` and create the .pro file

Answer (score 1):

There is no real answer to this question, just personal preference.

Many projects will include build scripts for a certain IDE (like the `*.pro` files you mentioned) but most often[citation needed] you will just pick the one that you like best.

Most IDE's provide easy methods for setting up projects for existing code, and many integrate with autotools quite well (the `./configure && make` is autotools at work).

So if the project has IDE project files feel free to use them if you find it convenient, but I would recommend finding an IDE that you like and getting used to it, that will generally make you more productive in the end[citation needed].

Comment: note: `./configure && make && sudo make install` isn't necessarily autotools. often autotools is used to _generate_ these files, but you can also write your own `configure` script (which is the traditional UNIX Way[tm]).

Comment: Really! I never knew that people wrote their own configure.  You learn something every day :D

Comment: But I think I will keep my answer as it because I think that autotools generated configures are much more common now days.

Comment: I would imagine so, but note that autotools is widely hated: see http://freecode.com/articles/stop-the-autoconf-insanity-why-we-need-a-new-build-system. many projects use other things to generate their `configure` scripts or skip them entirely, too, e.g. Xorg uses `imake`. see the ending of that reading for more.

Comment: @strugee: wasn't `imake` deprecated and substituted by autotools around the time Xorg went modular?

Comment: @ninjalj no idea. *googles it* yep, looks like they use autotools now.